# Change flex rows depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of hexagons that I want to change depending on the screen size.
What I currently have is:

```css
.hexagon-container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  }
.hex-row {
  margin-top       : -15px;
  display          : flex;
  background-color : transparent;
}
.hex {
  background-color : #343434;
  margin    : 1px;
  width     : 50px;
  height    : 57.5px;
  clip-path : polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-container left">
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex hex-main"></div>
    <div class="hex "></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is it changes to something like this when the screen size shrinks:

```css
.hexagon-container {
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  }
.hex-row {
  margin-top       : -15px;
  display          : flex;
  background-color : transparent;
  }
.hex {
  background-color : #343434;
  margin    : 1px;
  width     : 50px;
  height    : 57.5px;
  clip-path : polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-container left">
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex hex-main"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It does not have to be using the grid structure I have made I just want to use something like a media query so when the screen width shrinks the grid structure goes from:
4
3
to
1
2
1
2
1

I also want to be able to switch the hexagon with the class hex main from element 2 to element 1 on shrink.

Is this possible to do without javascript?

Thank You

Comment: read this: https://dev.to/afif/responsive-hexagon-grid-without-media-query-57g7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` (in *.hex-row*) and wrap new line with `flex-basis: 100%;` (in *.break-column*) and apply them in different breakpoints via `@media`.

Something like this (I've created *.break-column* and *.break-column-xs*):

```css
.hex-row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hex {
    background-color: #343434;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 57.5px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
    margin-bottom: -14px;

}

.break-column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .break-column-xs {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"></div>
      <div class="break-column-xs"></div>
      <div class="hex hex-main"></div>
      <div class="hex"></div>
      <div class="break-column"></div>
      <div class="hex"></div>
      <div class="break-column-xs"></div>
      <div class="hex"></div>
      <div class="hex"></div>
      <div class="break-column-xs"></div>
      <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `hex-row` is not needed. Replace `hexagon-container` styles with `hex-row`s styles and remove `hex-row` from `html` and `css`.